# Sitecore giving the values and I need to add in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sitecore, rating

I need to add sitecore values in current and potential places. Can you read the values using `.pointerValue` in jQuery?

We have to read the value using html label, or , adding a label with a class.

[image]
[image]

How to read the values in jQuery?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var currentValue = 30;         

    if (currentValue > 0 && currentValue <= 20) {
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-current").find('div').removeClass();
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-current").find('div').addClass('pointerbgG');
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-current .pointerbg .pointerValue").text(currentValue);
    }
    else if (currentValue >= 21 && currentValue <= 38) {
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-current").find('div').removeClass();
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-current").find('div').addClass('pointerbgF');
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-current .pointerbg .pointerValue").text(currentValue);
    }
    else if (currentValue >= 39 && currentValue <= 54) {
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-current").find('div').removeClass();
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-current").find('div').addClass('pointerbgE');
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-current .pointerbg .pointerValue").text(currentValue);
    }
    //Potential Value Starts
    var potentialValue = 50;

    if (potentialValue > 0 && potentialValue < 20) {
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential").find('div').removeClass();
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential").find('div').addClass('pointerbgG');
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential .pointerbg .pointerValue").text(potentialValue);
    }
    else if (potentialValue > 21 && potentialValue < 38) {
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential").find('div').removeClass();
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential").find('div').addClass('pointerbgF');
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential .pointerbg .pointerValue").text(potentialValue);
    }
    else if (potentialValue > 39 && potentialValue < 54) {
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential").find('div').removeClass();
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential").find('div').addClass('pointerbgE');
        jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential .pointerbg .pointerValue").text(potentialValue);
    }
    //Potential Value Ends
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would advise `.text()` feature of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/text/ If you need more assistance, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my comment, `.text()` can be used as both a Getter and a Setter. So for example, you can read the value like so:

```
var pv = parseInt(jQuery("#tab2 .floating-potential .pointerbg .pointerValue").text().trim());
```

The `parseInt()` will convert a String value into the Integer. Example: `parseInt("43")` will return a Int type with value 43.

The `.text()` will read the TextNode from the object `<span class="pointerValue">43</span>`, this will result in the String `"43"`.

The `.trim()` will remove any white spaces from the String object, if any are found. You don't have to use it.

So `.text().trim()` will read the string `"43"` and pass it to `parseint()` that will type cast it to the integer 43 and store it in the variable `pv`.

Hope that helps. If you need more help, please post a more complete example.